# Streaming Video from camera to local devices through Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming

I'm making an app right now that streams video through Multipeer connectivity. It will also eventually need to record said video stream, but that's another question for another day.

Here's my main class at the moment

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import MultipeerConnectivity

class FilmingVC: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{

    //Video
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
    var videoDeviceOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput!
    var sessionQueue: dispatch_queue_t!

    //Multipeer
    var peerID: MCPeerID!
    var session: MCSession!
    var browser: MCBrowserViewController!
    var assistant: MCAdvertiserAssistant!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Video
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

            let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

            // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
            for device in devices {
                // Make sure this particular device supports video
                if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
                    // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
                    if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                        captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                        if captureDevice != nil {
                            print("Capture device found")
                            beginSession()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        //Multipeer
            self.peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
            print( UIDevice.currentDevice().name )
            //self.session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .Required)
            self.session = MCSession(peer: self.peerID)
            self.session.delegate = self

            // create the browser viewcontroller with a unique service name
            self.browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "LCOC-Chat", session: self.session)
            self.browser.delegate = self

            // tell the assistant to start advertising our fabulous chat
            self.assistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType:"LCOC-Chat", discoveryInfo:nil, session:self.session)
            self.assistant.start()

    }

    /***** Video *****/
    func focusTo(value : Float) {
        if let device = captureDevice {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(value, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
                })
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                //error message
                print("Can't change focus of capture device")
            }
        }
    }
    func configureDevice() {
        if let device = captureDevice {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.focusMode = .Locked
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                //error message etc.
                print("Capture device not configurable")
            }
        }

    }
    func beginSession() {

        configureDevice()
        do {
            //try captureSession.addInput(input: captureDevice)
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            updateDeviceSettings(0.0, isoValue: 0.0)
        } catch {
            //error message etc.
            print("Capture device not initialisable")
        }
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, atIndex: 0)
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
    func updateDeviceSettings(focusValue : Float, isoValue : Float) {
        if let device = captureDevice {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(focusValue, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
                    //
                })

                // Adjust the iso to clamp between minIso and maxIso based on the active format
                let minISO = device.activeFormat.minISO
                let maxISO = device.activeFormat.maxISO
                let clampedISO = isoValue * (maxISO - minISO) + minISO

                device.setExposureModeCustomWithDuration(AVCaptureExposureDurationCurrent, ISO: clampedISO, completionHandler: { (time) -> Void in
                    //
                })

                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                //error message etc.
                print("Can't update device settings")
            }

        }
    }
    func addVideoOutput() {

        videoDeviceOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoDeviceOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Camera Session", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
        videoDeviceOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: sessionQueue)
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDeviceOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(videoDeviceOutput)
        }
    }

    /***** Multipeer *****/
    @IBAction func sendVideo(sender: UIButton) {
        // Bundle up the text in the message field, and send it off to all
        // connected peers
        addVideoOutput();
        if self.session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
                do {
                     let videoStream: NSOutputStream = try self.session.startStreamWithName("video", toPeer: self.session.connectedPeers[0])

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                    presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func showBrowser(sender: UIButton) {
        // Show the browser view controller
        self.presentViewController(self.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func updateChat(text : String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

    }
    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    func browserViewController(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController, shouldPresentNearbyPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    /****** Session *****/
    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        // Called when a peer sends an NSData to us

        // This needs to run on the main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("Incoming data:::")
        }
        print("111111111")
    }
    func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state {
        case MCSessionState.Connected:
            print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")

        case MCSessionState.Connecting:
            print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")

        case MCSessionState.NotConnected:
            print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
        }
        print("22222222")
    }
    func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress) {
        print("33333333")
    }
    func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) {
        print("4444444")
    }
    func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        print("555555555")

    }
```

Inside this function

```
@IBAction func sendVideo(sender: UIButton) {
// Bundle up the text in the message field, and send it off to all
// connected peers
addVideoOutput();
if self.session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        do {
             let videoStream: NSOutputStream = try self.session.startStreamWithName("video", toPeer: self.session.connectedPeers[0])

        } catch let error as NSError {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

I was wondering what a good way would be to stream the video through the NSOutputStream, or if that was even the correct function to call. I'm daftly out of my element and could really use some help. Thanks!